# Get original date string from Date Object

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am using Hapi and JOI. It automatically converts string date to Date Object.

Is it possible to extract the string date format which was sent from client?

Here is an example:

`const startDate = new Date('2017-04-25T21:00:00-09:00')`

From this date object I want to extract `2017-04-25T21:00:00-09:00` string from startDate. I have also included moment.

Comment: The standard does not define a property or a method to return it. But given you know the format - you can build it yourself.

Comment: I can't guess client's date format. The JOI middleware parse the string into date object and I don't have access to JOI code

Comment: If you don't know the format the data is passed, how do you know it would be parsed into anything meaningful?

Comment: We can do this with moment(startDate).format()

Comment: I guess I need to change JOI logic to not to parse string into date object

Comment: `moment(startDate).format()` returns utc string in my case